# Remove all the elements of the array in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have written a function which is triggered by a dropdown list's onChange event.
Once the function is triggered, it load data from rest API according to the parameter value. However, the array which I have used to store those data is not cleared in the subsequent dropdown change events. As a result, when the user change the dropdown multiple times, the array grows with its previously loaded data.

for example:
In first drop down change => ['A','B','C']
2nd drop down change => ['A','B','C','E','F','G'] instead of ['E','F','G']

My code is as follows:

```
onDropdownChange = (e) => {
    var newArray = [];

// To remove all the elements of newArray
    newArray.forEach((e1,idx, arr) => {
      
        newArray.splice(idx,1);
      
    });

    console.log(newArray);
    const url = 'https://abcdefgh...../' + e + '/readings?today';
    newArray = this.state.data.slice();
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      var response_arr = res.data.items;
      res.data.items.forEach((item, index) => {
        newArray.push({ time: res.data.items[index].dateTime, TM: res.data.items[index].value })
      })
      
     let sortedArray = newArray.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.time).getTime() - new Date(b.time).getTime());
     this.setState({ data: sortedArray });
     this.fetchChart();
    });
  }
  fetchChart = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return <CustomLineChart data={data} />
  }

  render(){
    const {items} = this.state;
    var data = [];
    const itemList = items.map(item => {
        return <tr key={item.dateTime+''+item.value}>
            <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{item.dateTime}</td>
            <td>{item.measure}</td>
            <td>{item.value}</td>
        </tr>
    });
    return (
      <div>   
              {this.fetchChart()}
              <CustomDropdownList changeLink={this.onDropdownChange.bind(this)} />
              
      </div>
  );


  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Can anybody assist me to resolve this issue?

Comment: `newArray = [];` Just assign a new empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the previous data with

```
newArray = this.state.data.slice();
```

You do not need that.. In fact you do not need any of this if you want to create a new array with new options.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the results to `newArray` which starts out empty that you tried to clear, then it's set to the existing data with additional data added. Also, avoid using var.

```
var newArray = [];

    // This is already empty
    newArray.forEach((e1,idx, arr) => {
      
        newArray.splice(idx,1);
      
    });

    // This will always be empty
    console.log(newArray);

    const url = 'https://abcdefgh...../' + e + '/readings?today';

    // Existing data, remove this
    newArray = this.state.data.slice();
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      var response_arr = res.data.items;
      res.data.items.forEach((item, index) => {

        // This is where new data is being added to existing
        newArray.push({ time: res.data.items[index].dateTime, TM: res.data.items[index].value })
      })
```